# Retval[0] does not have value : tf.cond(condition, net1, net2)

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I was trying to use `tf.cond()` to create 2 different graphs based on a condition. On, both the graphs we want to have weight regularization loss and thus we use `tf.losses.get_regularization_loss()`. Here is a pseudo code of our project

```
 def net_1(x,y):
  statement 1 (has trainable params)
  statement 2 (has trainable params)
  return
```

```
def net_2(x,y):
 statement 1 (has trainable params)
 statement 2 (has trainable params)
 statement 3 (has trainable params)
 return
```

```
step = tf.get_or_create_global_step()


tf.cond(tf.greater(step, 100), net_1, net_2)
loss = 0.0
loss += tf.losses.get_regularization_loss()
```

If we keep the `tf.losses.get_regularization_loss()` we get the error:

> Retval[0] does not have value

Otherwise, there is no error.

Is there any special care to be taken with `tf.cond()` if we want to impose `tf.losses.get_regularization_loss()`.

Comment: In your pseudo code you just call return. Do you return a value? Have a look at the [example](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond#example) in the docs.

Comment: Exactly same issue here also trying to use different losses based on the step. Even with returning the tensor it doesn't work. Toy example from [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond#example) works. The below answer is wrong. Doc indicates clearly that tf.cond takes functions and not tensors. As a workaround it works by creating the tensors upfront and giving a lambda to the tensor, but this means that the tensors are created all the time. Not sure how to fix this. Which TensorFlow version are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

Same issue, I fixed it by replacing tf.cond (which relates to regularizations) by two similar functions...Can't find better solution now.